# Let's start collecting our HNQ data

Tags: discusión, hnq

I am interested in learning more about how exposure via the Hot Network Questions (HNQ) list affects our efforts to attract more participants to Spanish Language Beta SE (SLB) and stimulate sustainable growth.

In response to a question I asked at SE Meta, [someone outlined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310482/287826) how it would be possible to become quickly aware when one of our questions at SLB hits the big time:

> There is no such thing built into the network itself. You can probably use the RSS feed for Hot Questions: https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions and have your RSS client filter for the site(s) you're interested in.

The only experience I have with RSS is in the context of downloading podcasts with some ancient software called *juice*.  Does anyone here want to give it a try and then outline exactly how to do it?

Related to this: would someone like to collect data on rate of growth of the site, with a couple of regularly updated graphs?  Perhaps, for example: rate of growth of number of people participating here for the first time; some measure of quality of posts of new arrivals.